# What is a Council?

Tags: early-church

In this other question a **Council** was mentioned - [Are Orthodox Christians all the same faith?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1271/are-orthodox-christians-all-the-same-faith)

What is a council? Was it something in the early church?  What was its purpose and function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A council is usually a gathering or conference of church (the body of Christ, not the building) leaders (or bishops) which decides on church doctrine and practice.

[Wikipedia on Ecumenical councils](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ecumenical_council)

[Catholic Major Councils of the Church](http://www.dailycatholic.org/history/councils.htm).

Comment: The word isn't limited to churches.

Comment: @DJClayworth I am only defining it within the scope of the original question.